# I am having several major warnings after aab file upload on the play console

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-console, android-app-bundle

I have made the game via Unity engine.
Some warnings while releasing my app on play console that are coming are as follows~

1. You must complete the advertising ID declaration before you can release an app that targets Android 13 (API 33).
2. This release will not be available to any users because you haven't specified any testers for it yet.
3. There is no deobfuscation file associated with this App Bundle. If you use obfuscated code (R8/proguard)...
4. This App Bundle contains native code, and you've not uploaded debug symbols. We recommend you upload a symbol file to make your crashes and ANRs easier to analyze and debug.

How to get rid of these?

And I turned on IL2CPP instead of MONO to choose ARMv64 cuz 32 bit is showing error in play console. Is it okay?
After doing that some gradle errors and all came in Unity and every now and then a dialog box saying "Resolving App dependencies" come forward in Unity and the bar of that dialog box remains at 0%. Please explain me what is happening and how can I fix these things!

Comment: For the first one you need to add <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" /> to the android manifest. For the second one you need to add testers in your play console.

Comment: I have built the game in Unity not Android studio. How to add the Ad id? The ad id is already in the code.
And i did add some mail id of testers in the option in play console. How can I add it again or edit it?